# Create list of lists from list of json objects ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a list of json objects something like this:

```
test = [{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}, {"a": 4, "b": 5, "c":6}]
```

I want to fetch the fields `'a'` and `'c'` from the above test list to create a list of list something like this:

```
[[1, 4], [3, 6]]
```

The idea is to make a list of all the values of a, then the values of c.

When I am using pluck:

```
test.pluck(:a, :c)
```

I am getting output like this:

```
[[1, 3], [4, 6]]
```

One approach I tried which is working fine.

```
res = []
res << test.pluck(:a)
res << test.pluck(:c)
```

But I am thinking it would be better if I get one or two liner solution,

 with or without `inbuilt function` because the number of fields in the future may increase.

Comment: Good question, but “...”fields `'a'` and `'c'`” should be “fields `:a` and `:c`”. It would be better to assign a variable to an array of those keys (e.g., `target = [:a, :b]`), so that readers could refer to that variable in answers and comments without having to define it ( just as they can refer to `test`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You were looking for following,

```
%i(a c).map { |x| test.map { |e| e[x] } }
```

Comment: It is working perfect. Can you please explain it a little bit?

Comment: first check how map works to provide data in array, so then test this -> `test.map { |e| e[:a] }` which will provide you `[1, 4]` so for `:c` so I have iterated this code on one more map iterated on [:a, :c] array which provided array of array.

Comment: @ray, sorry, I didn't see the big difference between `[[1, 4], [3, 6]]` and `[[1, 3], [4, 6]]`.

Comment: @SebastianPalma I guess, me too

Comment: `test.map { |e| e[x] }` could be `test.pluck(x)`

Comment: My initial reaction was that this was relatively inefficient, but since hash lookups are very fast and have a computational complexity close to `O(1)`, if `n`is the number of keys of interest (`2` in the example), your solution has a computational complexity *close to* the minimum possible of `O(n*test.size)`. Moreover, your solution reads well, but would read better, and be slightly more efficient, if you were to adopt @3limin4t0r‘s suggestion. Good answer.

Comment: @CarySwoveland helped as I did not think about *computational complexity* initially.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`Array#transpose`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Array.html#method-i-transpose) on the `pluck` result. Which assumes the array represents rows or columns and swaps the representation around.

```
test.pluck(:a, :c).transpose
#=> [[1, 4], [3, 6]]
```

Comment: ...the pure Ruby equivalent being `test.map { |h| h.values_at(:a, :c) }.transpose`. Good answer.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yep, but OP already uses `pluck` and tagged the question with [tag:ruby-on-rails], so I went with `pluck` since it's a lot shorter. But providing a pure Ruby equivalent doesn't hurt, and is useful for readers who don't use Rails.